# Moving Microsoft Identity EF into separate class library

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I've created an MVC5 application using individual user accounts, which automatically adds in the relevant authentication, Entity Framework & Owin references.

Is there an easy way to move the authentication's Entity Framework into a separate project?

Comment: The only real answer anyone can give you is "Yes, it's possible." What have you tried? (See: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Give it a go, and then ask specific questions if you run into issues.

Comment: For others looking, this question is asked/answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29519572/1467014